# Provide a counter example to the claim that "for every set S, if ∅∈P(S) , then ∅∈S

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Provide a counter example to the claim that "for every set S, if $\emptyset\in P(S)$ , then $\emptyset\in S$

This is a false statement but I don't know the counter example of it.
What could be the best counter example to prove that the claim is false?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement “$\emptyset\in P(S)$” is true for every set $S$.

Since $\emptyset\notin\emptyset$, the counterexample has been found.

Comment: if we take set S to be a empty set then is the claim true

Comment: @RoneelKumar The statement “If $\emptyset\in P(\emptyset)$ then $\emptyset\in\emptyset$” is false.

Comment: yes i got my answer but i asked it again since your answer stated it is true for every set..S

Comment: @RoneelKumar: There are two different statements. One of them, "$\emptyset \in \mathcal P(\emptyset)$" is true. The other, "If $\emptyset\in\mathcal P(\emptyset)$ then $\emptyset\in\emptyset$", is false.